# ¿Cómo hacer para ingresar una fila que sea sumatoria parcial de otras filas?

Tags: sum

Tengo una tabla a la cual debo sumar sus columnas discriminadas por mes y año, y agregarle una sumatoria de todo el año como partición de la tabla. Se suman varios años, y en consecuencia, varias particiones.
He desarrollado un código que intenta dar con ello, pero me acusa un error en la fila Group By
Este es el código:

````
    YEAR(Fecha) AS [Año], 
    MONTH(Fecha) AS [Mes], 
    COUNT(*) AS Registros, 
    SUM(Total * t.suma) AS Total, 
    SUM(Neto * t.suma) AS Neto, 
    SUM(iva * t.suma) AS IVA, 
    SUM(Ret_NG * t.Suma) AS [Ret.NG], 
    SUM(Ret_EX * t.Suma) AS [Ret.EX],
    SUM(Ret_IB * t.Suma) AS [Ret.IB],
    SUM(Ret_IG * t.Suma) AS [Ret.IG],
    SUM(Ret_IM * t.Suma) AS [Ret.IM],
    SUM(Ret_IP * t.Suma) AS [Ret.IP],
    SUM(Ret_IN * t.Suma) AS [Ret.IN],
    SUM(Ret_IVA * t.Suma) AS [Ret.IVA],
    SUM(Ret_OT * t.Suma) AS [Ret.OT],
    SUM(Total) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Fecha) ORDER BY YEAR(Fecha), MONTH(Fecha)) AS [Total por Año],
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Fecha) ORDER BY MONTH(Fecha)) = 1 THEN '---' ELSE '' END AS [Separador]
FROM dbo.IVA_Compras c 
INNER JOIN dbo.AFIP_Tipo_Comprobantes t ON t.Codigo = c.TDC
WHERE c.IdEmp = 9 AND t.IdEmp = 9 --AND Confirmada = 1 
GROUP BY YEAR(Fecha), MONTH(Fecha)
ORDER BY YEAR(Fecha), MONTH(Fecha);```

No sé cómo se empalma un OVER partition, por lo que agradeceré cualquier ayuda. Gracias.
````

Comment: Y la base de datos es......? Además este tipo de preguntas requiere usar algo como http://sqlfiddle.com/